# Spring – Read file from resources image folder

Tags: spring

I want to use  spring boot read file from resources image folder but I am get error :class path resource [oyak.png] cannot be opened because it does not exist

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("oyak.png");

InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();

File file = resource.getFile();
```

and

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:oyak.png");

InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();

File file = resource.getFile();
```

Comment: Because it isn't a file. A file, in the sense of a `java.util.File` is a physical file on the filesystem. This isn't a file it is a resource from within a jar, which can only be read through an `InputSream`.

Comment: As stated read the inputstream, there is no file.